# How can I redefine the type() of instances of my Python class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, types, instance

I'm doing some debugging and need to ensure instances of my class have a specific type, e.g. `<type 'list'>`, when `type()` is called.

The other option is redefining `type()` so it returns a different value when instances of my class are passed to it.

For example:

```
class Test:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'anything'
```

allows me to set my own value when the instance is treated as a string e.g. `str(Test())`. I want something similar for `type(Test())`:

```
class Test:
    def __type__(self):
        return type([])
```

(not valid)

Comment: You can't. Are you *sure* you need to match that type, a subclass won't do?

Comment: In other words, please tell us about the reason why you think you need this, this sounds a lot like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm debugging code that uses type(), which I need to "fool", so I can use my own objects instead of list. Also I want to know for theoretical reasons and understanding.

Comment: If the code explicitly expects <list>, you may be stuck: the original code should have been duck-typed.

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this is to use meta classes and define types. Here's a simple example of how you can do that.

**Meta class definition and inheritance**

```
# Meta class
class TypeClass(type):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
                return super(TypeClass, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(TypeClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


# Class directly inheriting from the meta class.
class ObjectClass(metaclass=TypeClass):
        pass


# Class that has indirectly inherited from the meta class.
class TestClass(ObjectClass):
        pass
```

**Tests**

Let's test our `TypeClass`:

```
test = TypeClass
print("mro: {} \ntype: {} \nrepr: {}".format(
          test.__mro__,
          type(test),
          repr(test)
      ))

mro: (<class '__main__.TypeClass'>, <class 'type'>, <class 'object'>) 
type: <class 'type'> 
repr: <class '__main__.TypeClass'>
```

Now let's test our `ObjectClass`:

```
test = ObjectClass
print("mro: {} \ntype: {} \nrepr: {}".format(
          test.__mro__,
          type(test),
          repr(test)
     ))
```

Displays:

```
mro: (<class '__main__.ObjectClass'>, <class 'object'>) 
type: <class '__main__.TypeClass'> 
repr: <class '__main__.ObjectClass'>
```

Finally, let's test our `TestClass`:

```
test = TestClass

print("mro: {} \ntype: {} \nrepr: {}".format(
          test.__mro__, 
          type(test), 
          repr(test)
      ))
```

Displays:

```
mro: (<class '__main__.TestClass'>, <class '__main__.ObjectClass'>, <class 'object'>) 
type: <class '__main__.TypeClass'> 
repr: <class '__main__.TestClass'>
```

**Answer to the question**

So, here is an answer to your question. Although, it would be useful if you say why you're doing this. Perhaps there is a better way for implementing what you're trying to achieve here!

```
class TypeClass(list):
        def __new__(cls, args):
                return super(TypeClass, cls).__new__(cls, args)

        def __init__(self, args):
                super(TypeClass, self).__init__(args)


# class ObjectClass(metaclass=TypeClass):
#         pass


class TestClass(TypeClass):
        pass


test = TestClass
print("mro: {} \ntype: {} \nrepr: {}".format(
        test.__mro__,
        type(test),
        repr(test)
      ))


tests = {
        'test1': isinstance(TestClass, type(list)),
        'test2': isinstance(TestClass, list),
        'test3': type(TestClass) is type(list),
        'test4': type(TestClass) is list,
        'test5': type(TestClass) is type([]),
        'test6': type(TestClass) == type(list),
        'test7': type(TestClass) == type([]),
        'test8': type(TestClass) == type(type([]))
}

print('\n', *[item for item in tests.items()])
```

Which displays:

```
mro: (<class '__main__.TestClass'>, <class '__main__.TypeClass'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'object'>) 
type: <class 'type'> 
repr: <class '__main__.TestClass'>

('test3', True) ('test6', True) ('test4', False) ('test7', False) ('test5', False) ('test2', False) ('test1', True) ('test8', True)
```

Comment: How would I use this to make type(instance) == type([])?

Comment: I'll add it to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: There you go! I added it to the existing answer! But seriously, tell me what it is you wanna do. There might be a better way as this is very awkward. Frankly, I have been programming for 15 years and this is the first time I see the need for such an implementation, especially of an existing type!

Answer (score 0):

You can but I do not recommend doing it:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.__name__ = 'B'

print type(A())  # <class 'B'>
print type(A()) == B  # False, since it's actually not a type B
print type(A()).__name__ == 'B'  # True, since the name is 'B'
```

If you change the type completely instead of the name the type of the object will actually change.

```
class B(object):
    def x(self):
        return 'b'

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__ = B
    def x(self):
        return 'a'

print A().x()  # b
```

**Edit:** to answer the other part of your question: if you want to override type you can do it like this:

```
class A(object):
    pass

def x(x):
    return 'test'

__builtins__.type = x

print type(A())  # test
```

Comment: This does not really affect the type programmatically.  It changes what is printed, but if you do `print type(A()) == B` it will print `False`.

Comment: I thought that's what he wanted? I might have misunderstood.

Comment: He said, "need to ensure instances of my class have a specific type, e.g. <type 'list'>".  In your case, they don't really.  (They really have a type with the name `<type '__main__.list'>`.)  Your answer is probably the closest that can be gotten to the asked-for answer, but I don't think it quite qualifies.

Comment: He could still use it like this `type(A()).__name__ == 'B'  # True` depending on what he wants it for... but you're probably right that it won't solve it for him...

Comment: That is true.  I'll grant you that.

Comment: It's correct that I don't just want to change the name.

Comment: You are not just changing the name, you are *really changing the class* for a given instance. It'll change behaviour, it is not longer an instance of the original class.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is you are trying to do the wrong thing, probably because your previous experience was with a static typed language.

In python you should never check the types, you should check the behaviour instead.

Probably you need something like:

```
import collections

if isinstance(theElement, collections.Iterable):
    # iterable
else:
    # not iterable
```

Comment: That's still type-checking; you're just checking if `theElement` is an instance of a different (virtual) superclass.

Comment: I'm debugging code that uses type(), which I need to "fool".

Comment: @Qgenerator is this code in a library that you cannot fix? The open-source python libraries are quite open to receive pull requests. I have some doubts that you could be able to fool the `type()` because that's quite low level, and if you manage to do it, you will end-up breaking your other-class, as it will start to believe is something else.

Comment: It's for debugging purposes, I won't actually keep the ugly code.